# Generating Test Result Reports with Perl

Tags: perl, user-interface, report

I am looking for a method to generate reports using perl. Currently right now I have it set up that my perl parser parses test cases (command lines) and stores the important information, then using HTML I output a report. The issue here is that the test report and the rest result are in the same report (ie think of them being in the same row, one column describe test, and the other the result). So end up copy pasting which is inefficient and some times results in mistakes. Is it possible to generate a dynamic report with checkboxes and and such so lets say when a tester is done the testing he check it off, and print out a copy.

Thanks

Comment: And what is the tested project's language? perl as well? If yes, have you considered Test::Harness?

Comment: Well the test themselves are for a linux embedded board, a tester has to manualy perform the test, and mark them on the report. It would be nice to have a utility to do something like that without getting into javascript or html.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what you want.

Comment: essentially imagine, you have a nice template report (Web/Desktop) which describes each case, and has a checkbox or widget next to it a tester can check off as he performs the test. I have data to set up the report, I just need to rapidly prototype checkboxes and such so the user can quickly mark test as passing or failing

Comment: This has a vague smell of Testopia to me.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a Template module. A common one is Template::Toolkit
http://template-toolkit.org/